# Large WGAN-GP train loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

This is the loss function of WGAN-GP

```
gen_sample = model.generator(input_gen)
disc_real = model.discriminator(real_image, reuse=False)
disc_fake = model.discriminator(gen_sample, reuse=True)
disc_concat = tf.concat([disc_real, disc_fake], axis=0)
# Gradient penalty
alpha = tf.random_uniform(
    shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 1],
    minval=0.,
    maxval=1.)
differences = gen_sample - real_image
interpolates = real_image + (alpha * differences)
gradients = tf.gradients(model.discriminator(interpolates, reuse=True), [interpolates])[0]    # why [0]
slopes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(gradients), reduction_indices=[1]))
gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean((slopes-1.)**2)

d_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(disc_real)
d_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(disc_fake)

disc_loss = -(d_loss_real - d_loss_fake) + LAMBDA * gradient_penalty
gen_loss = - d_loss_fake
```

[This is the training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFosH.jpg)

The generator loss is oscillating, and the value is so big. 
My question is:
is the generator loss normal or abnormal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to note is that your gradient penalty calculation is wrong. The following line:

```
slopes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(gradients), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

should actually be:

```
slopes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(gradients), reduction_indices=[1,2,3]))
```

You are reducing on the first axis, but the gradient is based on an image as shown by the alpha values and therefore you have to reduce on the axis `[1,2,3]`.

Another error in your code is that the generator loss is:

```
gen_loss = d_loss_real - d_loss_fake
```

For the gradient calculation this makes no difference, due to the parameters of the generator only being contained in d_loss_fake. However, for the value of the generator loss this makes all the difference in the world and is the reason why this oszillates this much.

At the end of the day you should look at your actual performance metric you care about to determine the quality of your GAN like the inception score or the  Fréchet Inception Distance (FID), because the loss of discriminator and generator are only mildly descriptive.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and answer. You save my days. After changing the code, the all the disc_loss are negative, and all the gen_loss are positive. Are they reasonable or not?

Comment: This is the desired behavior. GANs are notoriously fickle and can exhibit all kinds of behaviors, even if coded correctly so it is hard to tell. Are the output images reasonable?

Comment: Yes, the output images looks reasonable. Thank you.